# How to make javascript exclude some mentioned variables?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var variable1 = conditions_for_variable_1;
var variable2 = conditions_for_variable_2;
var variable3 = conditions_for_variable_3;
var variable4 = conditions_for_variable_4;

if (variable1 && variable2 || variable3 || variable4) {window.open('website_A');}

else if (variable1 && variable2 && variable3 && variable4) {window.open('website_C');}

else if (variable1 ????? variable2 || variable3 || variable4) {window.open('website_D');}

else {window.open('website_E');}
</script>
```

I have a code similar to this above.
Translating the code, this is what I need to do:

```
if system detects variable1 + one between variable2, 3 or 4 = go to website A
else if all variables from 1 to 4 are simultaneously detected = go to website C
**else if variable1 is there but variables 2, 3 and 4 are absent = go to website D**
else go to website E
```

Well, I need to find out a command to go to website D defining when variable1 is detected, to also verify that other mentioned variables are excluded.

Is there any chance to do this?

Comment: eHHhhhhhhhhH???

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing? Define the conditions in the if-clauses and you are good to go. You can also do ***variable1 = function() {if (...) {return true;}}***

Comment: The problem is if I set else if condition variable1 alone, the other conditions above get overlap, so I would lost chances of dividing visitors to website a website b and website c coz meeting variable1 is too general, and setup alone disturb other ones.

So I need the system to detect that variables 2, 3 and 4 are excluded, while variable 1 is detected.
But I don't know if exists a command to exclude things.
&& means "and"; || means "or"; anything means "exclude"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else if variable1 is there but variables 2, 3 and 4 are absent`

can be writen as

`else if (variable1 && !variable2 && !variable3 && !variable4)`

There are a lot of combinations that are ambigous as to witch website to go to.

Another problem seems to be the order of which you check the different combinations. Website C would never be shown, because Website A is shown for all possible combinations for C and you check for A first.

You can use ! to negate a variable and if a variable simply doesn't matter, don't use it in the expression

Full example of what you describe:

`if (variable1 && ((variable2 + variable3 + variable4) === 1) {}
else if (variable1 && variable2 && variable3 && variable4) {}
else if (variable1 && !variable2 && !variable3 && !variable4) {}
else {}`

Comment: You're right, I made a whole mess even self-confusing myself.
I have now edited the main text above to make it have a sense at least.

BTW your answer looks perfect thanks. Will test it now.

Comment: Can you translate me this?
if (variable1 && ((variable2 + variable3 + variable4) === 1) {}

Wasn't my form correct?
if (variable1 && variable2 || variable3 || variable4) {}

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks a lot.